# How can a user with less than 2K reps participate in Suggested Edits Reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Can a user having less than 2K reputation points review Suggested Edits?

Kindly check the attached screenshot. [image]

Comment: The user reviewed own posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OP can always approve/reject suggested edits, regardless of their reputation. These are counted in their review stats.

As an example, the [following suggested edit review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6139855) shows OP's username on a gray background, depicting the fact that OP reviewed the suggested edit:

> [image]

Comment: I saw this today i.e on Nov 20 and the screenshot is of 3rd Nov.

Comment: @user1336087 20th Nov review is this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6275910

Comment: Thanks for making it clear by providing the link :)